# Find neareast values of a given interval

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have some measurements done every 100ms. I want to reduce the data by selecting data every 10s, or at least the closest value.

I do here a small serie as example, with 10s. 
I use a loop but I want to find a easy peasy way to do it without.

Suggestion ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 8,11,12,26,27,28,31,40,49]) 

time_span = 10 
delta_time = 3

time_10s = np.arange(0,int((max(data)//10)*10)+1,10)
index_list = []

for elt in time_10s:
    min_index = abs(data-elt).idxmin()
    min_value = abs(data-elt).min()
    if min_value < delta_time:
        index_list.append(abs(data-elt).idxmin()) 

print(data[index_list])
```

I also tried with some modulo but gives nothing :

```
A = data % time_span < delta_time 
B = data % time_span > (time_span - delta_time)
C = A | B
D = data[C == True].index.values
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want exactly? the average? or just the measurement at interval 30s. We need some more context

Comment: I want to reduce my data. In the example, I want at the end only 0,11,31,49 instead of the whole serie. So with a 10s interval, the closest values to 0,10,20,30,40 . 20 is skept because no value is found below 3s. My example works, but I think it can be better

Comment: ah I see you want to round all your numbers to the closest 10

Comment: Yes, I rewrite my unclear question. I tried to use modulo to reduce the numbers, but I still not have the closest values. At the end, I use a loop but I wonder if there is a better way without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
# Get array data for better performance
a = data.to_numpy(copy=False) # data.values on older pandas versions

# Use searchsorted to get right-side closest indices for each of bins
idx0 = np.searchsorted(a,time_10s,'right')

# Get right and left side differences for each of the bins
v1 = time_10s-a[(idx0-1).clip(min=0)]
v2 = a[idx0]-time_10s

# Compare those to see which ones from the left ones are closer
# and thus adjust the indices idx0 accordingly by 1    
idx1 = idx0-(v1<v2)

# Use those indices to get the indexed data and keep the valid ones
# based on the threshold delta_time    
data_f = data[idx1]
out = data_f[np.abs(data_f-time_10s)<delta_time]
```

Comment: Ok nice, I did not know converting to numpy was faster, will do that in my problems now. Then I guess I got to know better the Numpy functions. :)